# Oracle to_date SQL formatting issue,

Tags: sql, oracle, date-arithmetic

I am formatting time stamp field to 'DD/MM/YYYY' format to get all processed records on that date.

```
select count(*) from task_log where to_date (event_dt,'DD/MM/YYYY')= to_date('19/05/2015','DD/MM/YYYY');
```

The above query is returning 0 count.

```
select count(*) from task_log where to_date (event_dt,'DD/MM/YYYY')= to_date('19/05/0015','DD/MM/YYYY');
```

The above query is returning 29 count.

If I run:

```
select event_dt from task_log where to_date (event_dt,'DD/MM/YYYY')= to_date('19/05/0015','DD/MM/YYYY');
EVENT_DT
5/19/2015 9:35:23 AM
5/19/2015 9:35:23 AM
5/19/2015 9:37:22 AM
5/19/2015 9:37:23 AM
5/19/2015 9:37:32 AM
5/19/2015 9:37:53 AM
```

and so on...

```
select to_date (event_dt,'DD/MM/YYYY') as to_date_Farmatted from task_log
TO_DATE_FARMATTED
5/19/0015
5/19/0015
5/19/0015
5/19/0015
5/19/0015
```

The to_date format is formatting year to **0015**?

How to avoid formatting year to 0015 format? I need to my year in 2015 format. Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: mysql or oracle? you have both tag in your question

Comment: Queries 1 and 2 are identical how can 1 return 0 and the other 29?

Comment: ITs in oracle. Thanks

Comment: Queries 1 and 2 are not identical, Query 1 has year 2015, Query 2 year 0015, Thanks.

Comment: ah missed that.  from this we assume task_log event date is character... can we see structure to confirm that?  Hopefully you're not to_dating a date field already just for display purposes.

Comment: First and foremost, what is the data type of `event_dt` column? Is it timestamp, date or something else?

Comment: Its Date field. Stored proc calculating epoch to date and inserting data in that field

Comment: In Question, you mentioned, you field is TimeStamp???

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> to_date (event_dt,'DD/MM/YYYY')

Based on your reply to the comments,

1. Your database is **Oracle**
2. Your `event_date` column's data type is **DATE**.

Never apply **TO_DATE** on a **DATE** column. It forces Oracle to:

- first convert it into a string
- then convert it back to date

based on the **locale-specific NLS settings**. You need **TO_DATE** to convert a literal into date. For **date-arithmetic**, leave the date as it is.

All you need to do is:

```
select count(*)
   from task_log 
  where trunc(event_dt) = to_date('19/05/2015','DD/MM/YYYY');
```

Now, the catch is the **TRUNC** function. Remember, a DATE has both the datetime elements. So, you must keep in mind the time portion while comparing two dates.

Applying **TRUNC** would suppress any regular **index** usage. It is better to use a **Date Range** condition.

For example,

```
select count(*)
   from task_log 
  where event_date 
 between to_date('19/05/2015','DD/MM/YYYY')
    and to_date('19/05/2015','DD/MM/YYYY') + 1;
```

Comment: Its working. Buddy can you please remove ] from query.
Thanks for your help and time on this.

Comment: @VSRSarmaChinta You're welcome! Actually, there was a lot of information more to be added, and I needed sometime to format everything. Hope it helped you.