# Extract Date from a date attribute

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, date-formatting, date-arithmetic

So I have this table--

```
create table orders (
ono      number(5) not null primary key,
cno      number(5) references customers,
eno      number(4) references employees,
received date,
shipped  date);
```

Populated with the script below--

```
insert into orders values
(1020,1111,1000,'10-DEC-11','12-DEC-11');
insert into orders values
(1021,1111,1000,'12-JAN-12','15-JAN-12');
insert into orders values
(1022,2222,1001,'13-FEB-12','20-FEB-12');
insert into orders values
(1023,3333,1000,'12-MAR-12',null);
```

Now I'm trying to create a `PL/SQL Procedure` which takes a input as a month and displays orders for that particular month. It seems I just cant get the `EXTRACT()` right. Here is my code block

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST_REPORT
    (MONTH_NUMBER IN NUMBER )

    AS
     V_MONTH VARCHAR2(10);
    BEGIN

    SELECT RECEIVED INTO V_MONTH
    FROM ORDERS WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM TO_DATE(
    ORDERS.RECEIVED, 'DD-MON-RR'))=MONTH_NUMBER;
    END TEST_REPORT;
```

What am I doing wrong here? For the record it compiles and executes but doesnt show anything.

Many Thanks

Attempt 2

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST_REPORT
    (MONTH_NUMBER IN NUMBER )

DECLARE
   CURSOR C1 IS SELECT RECEIVED INTO V_MONTH
   FROM ORDERS
   WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM ORDERS.RECEIVED) = MONTH_NUMBER;
   V_DATE ORDERS.RECEIVED%TYPE;
BEGIN

     OPEN C1;
  LOOP
    FETCH C1 INTO V_DATE;
    IF C1%FOUND THEN  -- fetch succeeded
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('DATE ' || V_DATE);
    ELSE  -- fetch failed, so exit loop
      EXIT;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END TEST_REPORT;
```

[image]

Comment: Never apply TO_DATE on a DATE column. It forces Oracle to:

   1. first convert it into a string
    2. then convert it back to date

based on the locale-specific NLS settings. You need TO_DATE to convert a literal into date. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/30332190/3989608

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since 'received' is of type DATE, you shouldn't use TO_DATE on it. TO_DATE is used for parsing a string (VARCHAR2) into date format. To be precise, it should not cause you troubles but I've already face odd behaviors with this.

Replace the following query:

```
SELECT RECEIVED INTO V_MONTH
  FROM ORDERS
 WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM TO_DATE(ORDERS.RECEIVED, 'DD-MON-RR'))=MONTH_NUMBER;
```

With this one:

```
SELECT RECEIVED INTO V_MONTH
  FROM ORDERS
 WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM ORDERS.RECEIVED) = MONTH_NUMBER;
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(V_MONTH); --Print your result.
```

Further information and examples of EXTRACT can be found in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions052.htm).

Also, you should be aware that in case of more than one row that fits your query, an exception will be thrown since v_month is of type VARCHAR2. You should consider using a collection or iterating a cursor. A simple example of an implicit cursor, which perfectly fits your needs, can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/static.htm#CJAEDJEE).

EDIT: Following our conversation, here's a solution for your case:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST_REPORT 
(MONTH_NUMBER IN NUMBER ) 

AS 
    CURSOR C1 IS SELECT RECEIVED 
                   FROM ORDERS 
                  WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM ORDERS.RECEIVED) = MONTH_NUMBER; 
    V_DATE ORDERS.RECEIVED%TYPE; 
BEGIN 

    OPEN C1; 
    LOOP 
        FETCH C1 INTO V_DATE; 
        IF C1%FOUND THEN -- fetch succeeded 
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('DATE ' || V_DATE); 
        ELSE -- fetch failed, so exit loop 
            EXIT; 
        END IF; 
    END LOOP; 
END TEST_REPORT;
```

Comment: Hi Neria thanks...Still no output if it try `EXECUTE TEST_REPORT(01)` and `ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows` when I try `EXECUTE TEST_REPORT(03)`

Comment: I just added another part to my answer regarding this.

Comment: Yes I do expect more than one row being returned. How do I handle this though?

Comment: Check out example 6-14 here, it fits your needs precisely: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/static.htm#CJAEDJEE

Comment: Thats a PL/SQL that utilizes cursor. But How can I implement it here to establish what I need to do? I'm sorry I'm a noob.

Comment: Take the example and replace the SELECT clause with your SELECT clause. Then, create a local date variable to contain the current row's date instead of my_ename & my_salary, and finally add it to the dbms_output.put_line.

Comment: Also, example 6-14 prints result using DBMS window, is it explicit? or the result shows in SQL Query window as wel?

Comment: can you check my updated question please? I'm getting a compilation error

Comment: I've added screenshots. I think I didnt get the syntax right.. First of all I need a procedure. And I have tried to implement the cursor loop as you have suggested. I need more experience and thinking I think!
Is it the word `declare`? because in procedure its `AS`

Comment: Remove the "INTO V_MONTH" part.

Comment: I think that you get it right ±. We create a cursor for your query and then iterate every row in a loop. Thus, you don't need the 'INTO VARIABLE' in the query, because you fetch the data into a variable later in the loop.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98510/discussion-between-envym6-and-neria-nachum).

Answer (score 1):

> Just a though in another way to handle multiple records, we can use
>   BULK COLLECT as row-by-row processing is not at all recommended if
>   data volume is huge. Huge data --more context switching. Let me know
>   if this helps.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST_REPORT(
    MONTH_NUMBER IN NUMBER )
AS
TYPE v_rcvd
IS
  TABLE OF ORDERS.RECEIVED%TYPE;
  v_rcvd_tab v_rcvd;
BEGIN
  SELECT RECEIVED BULK COLLECT
  INTO v_rcvd_tab
  FROM ORDERS
  WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM ORDERS.RECEIVED) = MONTH_NUMBER;
  IF v_rcvd_tab.EXISTS(1) THEN
    FOR I IN v_rcvd_tab.FIRST..v_rcvd_tab.LAST
    LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('DATE ' || v_rcvd_tab(i));
    END LOOP;
  END IF;
END TEST_REPORT;
```

Comment: This indeed a better practice. I just thought id would be easier to start with cursors rather than with collections, but that's a good answer!